# Need to find out which MdiChild is holding the currently active control

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop, mdichild, mdiparent

I have an MdiContainer with 4 children inside.
Each individual child has a number of label which are styled as squares.
There are 3 rows featuring 3 squares per Child (so 3x3).
The labels are dragable from one child to another.
Each MdiChild has a StackPanel which is used to contain the rows.

When I perform a drag or a drop, i'd like to know which MdiChild were the ones involved in the drag(the origin) and the drop(the destination child).

I'm just having trouble figuring out the code to do so.

I've tried using visualtreehelpers and getparent but they haven't done the trick. Most pages I could find through googling deal with forms whereas i'm working in WPF.

Edit 1:
When testing to see if I was getting the answer I wanted, I used this code

```
string TheActiveMdi = Container.ActiveMdiChild.Name;
```

where "Container" is the name given to my MdiContainer.

For some reason the value put into the variable is just whichever is MdiChild is the last one written in my Xaml code, so it's not returning an accurate value. I have that code placed in my Drop event method.

Edit 2:
Within the drop event method, this code will allow me to access the label which was dragged:

```
Label sourceLbl = e.Data.GetData("System.Windows.Controls.Label") as Label;
```

If I use this code, I can access it's parent, which is a Stackpanel:

```
string LabelsParent = myObject.Parent.GetType().ToString();
MessageBox.Show(LabelsParent);
```

This tells me that it's a Stackpanel.

However what confuses me is that if I try to print it's name in a Messagebox:

```
MessageBox.Show(LabelsParent.Name);
```

then it simply returns "Stackpanel" whereas if I do the same with sourceLbl:

```
MessageBox.Show(sourceLbl.Name);
```

then it will in fact print it's name, which in this case is "testSquare"

Can anybody explain this or help me with my initial problem?